# SASS: Nested image slider

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I am a beginner level designer. I am try to learning nested image display. On my app there is one Iphone mobile screen. Inside the Iphone screen I want to display multiple image slider. For sliding the image I used [Splide-js](https://splidejs.com/getting-started/) package. I want to display my app like this [website](https://www.sherpashare.com/) and this is the [gif-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBJ0j.gif). I share my code in [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nested-image-scss-fepri?file=/style.scss). Really appreciate, if someone show me how to do that.

**This is my html**

```
<section id="section_feel-the-power">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div>
      <h2 class='section-title'>Take a seat <br> Feel the power.</h2>
      <p>We provide the platform to keep your maintaince on track and your tenants happy</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Assign jobs in an instant.</li>
        <li>Always see what's happening.</li>
        <li>Easy to setup and use.</li>
        <li>Be more sustainable.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-container">
      <div class="mobileCase">
 </div>
    <div class="splide mobile-splide" >
      <div class="splide__track">
        <ul class="splide__list">
          <li class="splide__slide" style="background-color: bisque;">
            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dtnhtcwwg/image/upload/v1597658337/Untitled_2_u2y8lo.png">
          </li>
          <li class="splide__slide" >
            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dtnhtcwwg/image/upload/v1597658337/Untitled_2_u2y8lo.png">
          </li>
          <li class="splide__slide" >
            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dtnhtcwwg/image/upload/v1597658337/Untitled_2_u2y8lo.png">
          </li>
          <li class="splide__slide" >
            <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dtnhtcwwg/image/upload/v1597658337/Untitled_2_u2y8lo.png">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**This is my scss file**

```
#section_feel-the-power {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 80px 0 120px 0;
  color: #1a444e;
  position: relative;

.mobileCase {
   width: 500px;
   height: 800px;
   background-position: center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
   background-image: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/dtnhtcwwg/image/upload/v1597659675/Untitled_2_zxiiim.png);
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
 }

 .splide__list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
}
 .splide__slide img{
  background-position: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 }
 .splide__pagination__page {
  display: none;
}

.splide__pagination__page.is-active {
  display: none;
}

.splide__arrow{
  display: none;
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your `<div class="splide">` inside a container, set the `overflow` to `hidden` and position it to where you want it to be on the device using `position: absolute;` and `top`, `left`, `width`, `height` respectively. I don't want to outright give you the answer, so do some fiddling. That should get you in the right direction.

Comment: I had one small issue. My slide does not looks like coming from mobile. It looks coming  outside of the mobile. This is how it looks like https://res.cloudinary.com/dtnhtcwwg/image/upload/v1597741493/ezgif.com-video-to-gif_hfoqxc.gif

Comment: @krisna I would recommend using a device with the screen set to transparent, and overlaying your content with that. And don't forget to set overflow to hidden!